# Query a column and a calculation of columns at the same time PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I have two tables, `Products` and `BundleProducts` that have o2o relation with BaseProducts.
A `BundleProduct` is a collection of `Products` using a m2m relation to the `Products` table.
`Products` has a `price` column and the price of a `BundleProduct` is calculated as the sum of the prices of its `Products`.

`BaseProducts` have columns like `name` and `description` so I can query it to get both `Products` and `BundleProducts`.

Is it possible to query and `sort by price` both for the `price` column of the `Products` and calculated `price` of the `BundleProducts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT name, description, price
FROM (
    SELECT name, description, price FROM products
    UNION
    SELECT bundle_products.name, bundle_products.description, sum(products.price)
    FROM bundle_products
    JOIN products on (<your join condition)
    GROUP BY bundle_products.name, bundle_products.description
) AS combined
ORDER BY price
```